# Use performant numpy.loadtxt to read 4-char ASCII columns as integer values (among other proper integer-valued columns)

Tags: numpy, csv, parsing

Is it possible somehow to convince `numpy.loadtxt` to read 4-char ASCII-valued columns as int32 (without resorting to using `converters=` argument)?

I can of course use `converters=` to pass a custom converter, but theoretically it could just reinterpret-cast ASCII bytes as int32 without slowing down the parsing by calling a Python func for every value. Alternatively, I could do parsing with two passes: first time for integer columns only and second time for short-string columns

One could image that a mixture of only-integer and short 4-char string columns could be parsed very efficiently for exteremely large files in a single pass, but does vanilla `numpy.loadtxt` support such feature?

Comment: A sample file and converter might help us better understabd what you are trying to do.  But generally fast compiled code is written to handle the most common straightforward cases.

Comment: "without slowing down the parsing by calling a Python func for every value." why is this such a concern? Theoretically, you can do this precisely once, then serialize the resulting array in an unambiguous format conducive to performant parsing (e.g. using `numpy.save`)

Comment: Yeah, there are plenty of workarounds, and I am not blocked by this in any way. But in some contexts (e.g. using NumPy for CSV parsing in Pyodide, and calling a Python lambda for every value in some column for a huge dataset can already be noticeable. And int-only + 4-char bypass parsing can be much faster than any float parsing and ofc generic mixed type parsing), it just simplifies things if fewer preprocessing steps can be made and temp data files stored around.